# Problems with function colorPicker.CP.cmyc

Tags: color-picker, cmyk

The function **colorPicker.CP.cmyc** from JavaScript ColorPicker 0.9 (http://www.dematte.at/colorPicker/) always produces following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'cmyc' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is simply wrong. The right function name is:

```
colorPicker.CP.cmyk
```

The difference is the last char. The documentations says **c** but the right char is a **k**.

Comment: sorry, I will fix this... maybe see the new version on http://www.dematte.at/cpn/ or https://github.com/PitPik/colorPicker